# Xamarin Android try/catch does not work with udp.SendAsync()

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, try-catch, udpclient

I've built a simple app that talks over UDP, to an endpoint at an IP the user specifies. It uses `System.Net.Sockets.UdpClient`, which works pretty well on Android - I'm able to send and receive packets fairly consistently. With one glaring exception... Exceptions. It seems to completely evade `try/catch`; my guess is the underlying implementation errors so hard that errors cannot be caught. For example:

```
UdpClient Udp { get; protected set; }

Udp.Connect("192.168.1.254"); // Any bad IP
try
{
    int bytesSent = await udp.SendAsync(bytes, bytes.Length);
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

When testing on an actual Android device, any UDP traffic sent to a bad IP consistently destroys the application.

The behavior gets crazier. For example, if I put the call out on a background thread, with a nested try/catch, like this:

```
Task.Run(ping).ConfigureAwait(false);

protected async Task ping()
{
    try
    {
        await checkIp();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
    }
}
```

Then there are some scenarios where I actually can get an Exception - but only in the outer catch! The throw occurs on the `SendAsync` call inside the inner try, but the inner catch misses it, landing only in the outer catch. The exception is a `System.Net.Sockets.SocketException` with type `ConnectionRefused`. Depending on how exactly I step through it, sometimes that gets caught there, sometimes not at all; when it's not at all, the app just implodes.

Is this expected behavior? Is Xamarin UdpClient just not supposed to be used? Bug? Better approach than `SendAsync`? Other?